# Get Distinct Value from Observable Collection Class

Tags: linq-to-sql, binding

I am using Linq-To-SQL.

I have made one class by inheriting ObservableCollection

This class has one constructor with Datacontext as parameter.

I have calling this construtor from my program and assigning it to the control's ItemSource property.

But I can't get distinct value in it..

```
 public class BindBookIssueDetails : ObservableCollection
        {
            public BindBookIssueDetails(DataClasses1DataContext dataDC)
            {
                foreach (Resource_Allocation_View res in dataDC.Resource_Allocation_Views)
                {
                    this.Add(res);
                }
            }
        }
```

```
private BindBookIssueDetails bResource;
bResource = new BindBookIssueDetails(db);
_cmbResource.ItemSource=bResource;
```

So what's the solution?

Plz Help...

Answer (score 2):

I would first suggest taking your query logic out of the constructor of the collection. That's a very unusual place for something like that.

But otherwise, the LINQ function you're looking for is called [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456.aspx).

Comment: i couldn't understand what u want say..
can u explain with sort example ?